# Building user level cache in Spring boot managed application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

I have built a spring boot application for the first time. I have about 10-12 user specific caches and 1 global cache in my application. User level caches are HashMap based.

```
Class userCache1 {
   private Map<Integer, MyObject> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
   
   public Map<Integer, MyObject> getDataMap() {
        return dataMap;
    }
    public void setDataMap(Map<Integer, MyData> dataMap) {
        this.dataMap = dataMap;
    }
    
    public dataMap get(int key) {
        if(dataMap.containsKey(key))
            return dataMap.get(key);
        else
            return null;
    }

    public void setData(int dataMap, MyData data) {
        dataMap.put(key, data);
    }
}
```

Now there has to be one instance of userCache1 for each registered user. I have similarly objects each holding various kinds of data that are required by multiple objects for the application to process the user requests. Some of the classes would required 5-10 of these caches such as userCache1...userCache5.

Below are my questions:

1. How would I tie the userCache1 to userId which is the primary key of the user of this application? Do I need another class that holds userId and userCache1? Wouldn't it create one such class for each of these user level caches just for the purpose of associating the cache with userId? Are there better options that I can use?
2. Based on the approach I take in #1, I would like to use DI to inject the required userCacheX objects to the constructor of the classes that require these caches to process the biz logic. I don't think that having a constructor with 5+ such caches is an elegant approach. What makes the most sense in this example as below

```
public class UserCache {
   private UserCache1 cache1;
   private UserCache2 cache2;
   ...
   private UserCacheN cacheN;

   UserCache(UserCache1...UserCacheN) {
     this.cache1 = cache1;
     ....
     this.cacheN = cacheN;
  
   }
   /*
   use the cache1...cacheN as needed in the body of this class
   */

}
```

In addition to user specific cache I have 1 or 2 global cache as well. I understand that spring enables caching which I would be using once I decide on the high level design.

All my user specific caches are HashMap based at this time. The content of most of these caches would NOT change during lifetime of the user once registered but I would assume that i should expire the caches to manage memory efficiently and optimize performance which can happen once I successfully build the application.

I am planning to use Spring Boot, Hibernate to persist these objects into the datastore.

What are my recommended design options for this problem?

Comment: The recommended design option would be to use an actual in-memory cache like Redis and avoid trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: A cache is holding information temporarily and is allowed to arbitrary forget information if resources get scarce. "Forgetting" information is called eviction in cache lingo. A cache usually does evict data by choosing entries that are accessed less frequently. Does this apply to the user cache you are describing? How much data is stored in a "user cache"? When and how is the content accessed?

Comment: Your user cache basically wraps a Java Map at the moment. Why don't you use a Map directly?

Comment: yes, the contents of cache could be evicted and I am fine with it. The data is read mostly once it is created. I am building a brand new app and I don't know how much data will be eventually stored as it has to scale based on the success of this software.

Comment: What do you mean by using a Map directly? I am using Java Map. Which Map are you referring to @cruftex?

Comment: Sorry, you ask for design advice, but it is totally unclear what you are trying to achieve. Maybe start a new question explaining what your application needs to do and avoid technical terms that lead into a specific direction.

Comment: I tried to summarize my design requirements in this post. My application has multiple classes each holding required data. I am trying to consolidate those caches under one class UserCache so that it is easy to autowire as many of the classes in my application would  need 5-10 of these userCache classes.